# Ошибка при записи в БД

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$startDate = time(); 
$endDate = mktime(date("h"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO timer(id, startDate, range, endDate) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("siii", $id, $startDate, $range, $endDate);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Ошибка:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'range, endDate) values(?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
```

Comment: А что за ошибка то?

Comment: 1) не привели $id, $range у вас может они пустые, а в базе они обязательны 2) покажите `show create table timer`, чтобы знали что должно туда писаться 3) саму ошибку покажите

Comment: почитайте [это](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), скорее всего достаточно будет `range` взять в кавычки (т.е. `\`range\``)

Comment: [Аналогичная проблема в SQLite + Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30752852/2076787): решение в целом такое же, завернуть в соответствующие кавычки идентификатор.

Answer (score 2):

Перед коннектом к mysqli надо всегда писать строчку

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

после этого БД начнет сама сообщать, какая именно ошибка произошла. Останется только прочесть и исправить.